# Where can I find documentation on what data/fields are on an am5chart event?

Tags: amcharts5

I have a line chart with bullets added. These bullets have tool tips and are clickable. When I get a click event from them I can see all the data from each line contained in ev.target.dataItem.dataContext. The problem is I don't know WHICH line was clicked on. I cannot find any information as to what fields are on ev or ev.target or ev.target.dataItem to see if I can see which line was selected.